# C++ Alternative to void* in one particular case

Tags: c++, c++11, callback, c++17, type-erasure

I was thinking about one usecase for `void*` in C and I was trying to translate that code into C++ in the most idiomatic way possible without loss of efficiency.  This is the problem and the following is the solution for it

```
void callback(void* args) {
    Something* something = static_cast<Something*>(args);
    // use something
}

Something something;
add_callback(callback, &something);
```

Here the callback is invoked whenever some event happens with the argument something.  The idiomatic way (help me find a better solution if you think it's not right) to go about doing this in C++ would be something like the 
following

```
Something something;
add_callback([=something]() { 
    // do something
});
```

and then `add_callback()` would internally erase the type of the lambda and store it in a `std::function<>` for calling back when the time comes.  The benefit of this over the older version is that the callback better encapsulates its state.

But the problem I saw with this is that this causes the unnecessary overhead of a virtual function dispatch for each time the callback is called.  (Assume even if there is no provable overhead, that it is overhead just because I am curious), the only solution I can think of is to use `std::any` here (but that requires the object to be copy constructible) and either make the signature of the callback uniform with an `std::any` as a member variable or just pass along the `std::any` to the function (stored as a function pointer) and give up encapsulation of the callback's state.  But something tells me there is a better solution...

Comment: I don't understand, why would `callback` take a `void*` if the thing it points to is *always* a `Something`? Why not just take `Something*`?

Comment: @Brian the library that provides `add_callback()` does not know that, for example, `event_new()` in libevent

Comment: @downvoter, can you please explain the reason for downvoting?

Comment: Or an example from the standard library, `qsort` and `bsearch`.

Comment: TBH, the cost of a virtual dispatch is negligible compared to the cost of everything else in pretty much any situation that involves asynchronous callbacks.

Comment: @Brian I understand, I just asked because I couldn't figure out a (good?) solution to eliminate that cost myself..  Take this as a purely hypothetical question!

Comment: @Curious: This is a question that begins by defining itself into a corner. No value types, because that requires copying. No indirect dispatching, because that "requires" virtual functions. Etc. It's not also clear which flaws of the C methodology it is you want fixed: the inability to provide arbitrary callables (functors and the like), the checking to see if the `void*` parameter is actually the type it's being cast to, or something else.

Comment: @NicolBolas I feel like I made it all clear in the question.  Can you suggest a change?  And as far ask I know there is no way in C to check if the type pointed to by a `void*` is the type you are casting to...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function template to streamline the use of complete types in C++ but there is no avoiding a `static_cast`.

Example:

```
struct CallbackHandler
{
   void doSomething() {}
}

template <typename T>
void cpp_callback(T* args)
{
   // Use args with full access to T.
   args->doSomething();
}

template <typename T>
void callback(void* args)
{
   cpp_callback(static_cast<T*>(args));
}

int main()
{
   add_callback(callback<CallbackHandler>, new CallbackHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get type erasure, type safety, zero overhead all at the same time.

The best I came up with is something like this:

```
typedef void (*func_t)(void *p);

template<typename T, void (T::*F)()>
struct CB_helper
{
    static void func(void *p)
    {
        T *t = static_cast<T*>(p);
        (t->*F)();
    }
};

template<typename T, void (T::*F)()>
func_t CB()
{
    return CB_helper<T, F>::func;
}
```

And then you can use it with:

```
struct Something
{
    void do();
};
Something some;
add_callback(CB<Something, &Something::do>(), &some);
```

The drawback is that you need a new `CB` for each type of callback you are going to use. You can do some smart metaprogramming to have just one version per number of arguments.